# How to keep values of radio elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**SOLVED:**

I am using jQuery to allow a user to dynamically add fields to a form and I am requiring that they select certain yes and no values. When I clone the row I need to keep the values on input radio elements but not on the text element. I was expecting that this would do it but no luck.

How would I keep the values on the radio elements?

Also when the previous node has radios selected the cloning duplicates the selection information. I DON'T want that to happen.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dynamic-node">
    <input type="text" name="custom-name[0]" value=""/>
        <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="haswood[0]" value="yes"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="haswood[0]" value="no"/>No
        <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="hasmetal[0]" value="yes"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="hasmetal[0]" value="no"/>No
        <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="hasplastic[0]" value="yes"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="hasplastic[0]" value="no"/>No
</div>

<div class="clone-node">Add Row</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$cloneNode = $( ".clone-node" );

$cloneNode.click(function(){
    var $newNode = $(".dynamic-node:last").clone(true);
    $newNode.find('input').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('name', $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) {
            return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']';
        }));
        $this.val('');
    });
    $newNode.insertAfter('.dynamic-node:last');
});
```

**Solution:**

Thanks to commenters below and borrowing their fresh set of eyes I resolved this by extending the code a little and making adjustment to elements based on their type and my needs:

```
$cloneNode = $( ".clone-node" );

$cloneNode.click(function(){
    var $newNode = $(".dynamic-node:last").clone(true);
    $newNode.find('input').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('name', $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) {
            return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']';
        }));

        if( $this.is('input:text') ) {
            $this.val('');
        }
        if( $this.is('input:radio') ) {
            $this.prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
    $newNode.insertAfter('.dynamic-node:last');
});
```

Comment: You're setting the value to the empty string. Don't do that if you want the values to remain. Just set the `checked` property to false.

Comment: is the $this.val('') causing the issue?

Comment: ARHG,,, great catch Aron. I reused an old code and I need a fresh pair of eyes this morning apparently,, Thank you! I'll have to break down the code a bit more :)

Also Mike, that was a helpful suggestion. Thanks!